# Create new user profile property from powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile

I have been trying to create a new user profile property using powershell, without any luck.

I have been reading up about [User Profile service cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906542.aspx) but I keep getting an error saying the cmdlet is not recognised.

Can any give me guidance as to what I am missing and maybe point me in the direction of a solution please?

Comment: you need to be more specific if you want people to answer this. Add source code and specific errors from PowerShell to give us something to go on

Answer (score 3):

Use `Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` before your commands.